# Observable forkJoin never execute pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Im trying to execute and get values from array of observables (each obtained from `literalsService`) using pipe. Here is the code:

```
translateLiterals() {
    const literalsToTranslate: string[] = [
    'certificate_title',
    'with_address',
    'hereby',
    'declare',
    'electronic_records',
    'proceeded_to_shipment',
    'return_address',
    'return_address',
    'addressee',
    'message_subject',
  ];
    const newArray: Observable<string>[] = [];
    literalsToTranslate.map(literal => newArray.push(this.literalsService.getValue('Ngwa.Ngwa', literal)));
    this.literalsArray$ = forkJoin([...newArray]).pipe(map((results) => {
      console.log(results);
      return results;
    }));
  }
```

Of course im subcribed to the pipe in the html side with:

`<ng-container *ngIf="literalsArray$ | async"></ng-container>`

but the `console.log()` never prints nothing... anyone knows why?

Comment: you forgot to subscribe to your observable. You can also use rxjs' "firstValueFrom"

Comment: also you are using the `.map()` incorrectly. `Array.map()` returns an array. You are doing a foreach.

Comment: @Carsten They use `async` in the template, so it will be subscribed there

Comment: What does `this.literalService.getValue` return? Does the observables generated from that complete? forkJoin will only go through when all observables have completed

Comment: even in the pipe(), the map operator is used incorrectly. You should use `tap()` for logging or invoking any intemediate steps

Comment: It's not related to the problem, but I would simplify the initialization of newArray to this: `const newArray = literalsToTranslate.map(literal => this.literalsService.getValue('Ngwa.Ngwa', literal));`

Comment: Are you sure that `literalsService.getValue` return an `Observable/Promise`? And are you sure there is no error happening in any of the calls?

Comment: All source Observables for `forkJoin()` need to emit at least once and complete, so this might by why you don't see anything.

Comment: I will answer one by one :

1- @Carsten: Im subcribed with the pipe and then calling it on the html.
2- @Liero: ```literalsToTranslate``` its an array so your comment makes no sense
3- @ShamPooSham: always return an observable, but how can i know if them all are complete?
4- @Liero: Is tap not used only when no value is expected to be returned?
5- @ShamPooSham: When I make it work I will make it prettier
6- @PoulKruijt: Yes im sure but i dont know if them all are complete...how can I know that?
7- @martin: How can I know if they are emited and completed?
Thx all for your help an time

Comment: exactly what you are commenting on, the method ```this.literalsService.getValue ('Ngwa.Ngwa', literal)``` never ends and waits for changes to the observables. I did not know because I had not written the method and I cannot change it now because it is used in many other places and it could break. I add the solution that I have created in case someone ever has the same problem or if you think it can be improved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the users @ShamPooSham and @martin say in the comments, the problem was that the method `this.literalsService.getValue ('Ngwa.Ngwa', literals)` was observing the changes of the literals and the method `forkJoin` never started as literals were not completed.
I have created a separate method to solve the problem and have added a `take` to the initial method:

New Method:

```
translateString(text: string): Observable<string> {
    return this.literalsService.getValue('Ngwa.Ngwa', text).pipe(
      switchMap((translated) => {
        if (!translated.startsWith('N/A')) {
          return of(translated);
        } else {
          return this.literalsService.getValue('Ngwa.Ngwa', text).pipe(
            skip(1), // First event translation comes not translated
            map((secondTryTranslation) => {
              return secondTryTranslation;
            }));
        }
      }),
    );
  }
```

Correction of the first method:

````
    translateLiterals() {
    const literalsToTranslate: string[] = [
    'certificate_title',
    'with_address',
    'hereby',
    'declare',
    'electronic_records',
    'proceeded_to_shipment',
    'return_address',
    'return_address',
    'addressee',
    'message_subject',
  ];
    const newArray: Observable<string>[] = [];
    literalsToTranslate.map(literal => newArray.push(this.translateString(literal).pipe(take(1)))); //<--- Here is the correction
    this.literalsArray$ = forkJoin([...newArray]).pipe(map((results) => {
      return results;
    }));
  }```
````

Answer (score 0):

Probably `this.literalsService.getValue('Ngwa.Ngwa', literal);` returns string.
If that's the case you need transform it to Observable with:

`of(this.literalsService.getValue('Ngwa.Ngwa', literal));`

Also `forkJoin` waits for all given streams to be completed, then emits value.

Comment: Nope, ```this.literalsService.getValue('Ngwa.Ngwa', literal);``` returns an Observable object

Comment: Could you provide `getValue` definition?